# Android Firebase SQLite crash on Kitkat & Lower

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

We're facing this crash within the firebase library out in the wild in large numbers; however haven't been able to reproduce this in-house. This seems to only affect android versions below Lollipop.

Stacktrace given below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkx$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to gain exclusive lock to Firebase Database's offline persistence. This generally means you are using Firebase Database from multiple processes in your app. Keep in mind that multi-process Android apps execute the code in your Application class in all processes, so you may need to avoid initializing FirebaseDatabase in your Application class. If you are intentionally using Firebase Database from multiple processes, you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call setPersistenceEnabled(true)) in one of them.
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbky.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbky.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkx.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmc.zzWz(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbml.zzXn(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbml.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbml$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1123)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:834)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:520)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:491)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:386)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:233)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:512)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:888)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:858)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:695)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1179)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:275)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbky.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbky.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbkx.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmc.zzWz(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbml.zzXn(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbml.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbml$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This is a single-process app, and we are initializaing firebase library in the Application onCreate()